# jQuery UI Tab, Active Tab

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I don't know how to reach active tab from code behind? So that, I redirect page to active tab. I want to only know active tab index {1 or 2 or 3} How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Straight out of the [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Events).

```
 $('#example').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
   ui.tab // anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
   ui.panel // element, that contains the contents of the selected (clicked) tab
   ui.index // zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
 });
```

So you want to get the ui.index

Comment: function SetTab(index) {
            $(function () {
                $('#tabs').tabs('select', index); void (0);
            });
        }

Comment: Page Load, i call it -->       this.InsertJScript(string.Format("SetTab('{0}')", 2));

Comment: It's working but i want to get active index instead of "2"  @Ohgodwhy